# Kickstart: create lvm volume group without partition

Tags: redhat, provisioning, lvm

I am trying to setup a redhat 7 kickstart for a server with 2 disks.
On the second disk I want to use the full disk without partitioning in lvm.
Once the system is installed, the config works:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb
vgcreate data /dev/sdb
lvcreate -l +100%FREE -n data data
mkfs.xfs /dev/mapper/data-data
echo -e "/dev/mapper/data-data\t/data\txfs\tdefaults\t0 1" >> /etc/fstab
mount /data
```

But I cannot manage to have the following partitioning to work as expected
The partitioning system on kickstart as I know it will only create a partition on /dev/sdb and the volume is create on /dev/sdb1 at the end.

I managed to workaround the issue by using a postscript, but I compiled packages to install in this folder, so I would need the formating to be done before at least in a pre script if the partitioning is not possible.